# How do I add an 's' to the end of an output sentence?

Tags: .net, regex

How would I add a character to the end of my output? I am scraping some data, I am using a regex to get what I want. I got it but I have to add an 's' to the end of the sentence.

The sentence changes every time so I can't just do a replace. I think I am using the .NET regex engine.

Comment: Can you show some code as to what you are currently doing and why it is not working? Also what you would like to have the output look like versus what it currently is?

Comment: err... 'sentence = String.Concat(sentence, ".")' not working for you?  or any of the shorter ways to write it?

Comment: Are you saying this has to be done purely in a regex, and in the same regex that you use to scrape data from the page you load? Why?

Answer (score 3):

If you simply want to append a "s" to the string, just use `newstring = oldstring + "s"`.

If you need to add the s before the punctuation characters at the end of the sentence, you could search for `(?=\W+$)` and replace that with `s`. I can provide a code snippet if you say which language you're using. However, this assumes punctuation to be present (it won't match if the strings ends in an alphanumeric character).

In VB.net, for example:

```
ResultString = Regex.Replace(SubjectString, "(?=\W+$)", "s")
```

If you need to add an "s" at the end of the string, before any punctuation if present, then you can search for `(?=\W+$)|(?<!\W)$` and replace with `s`.

As an annotated multiline regex:

```
(?=\W+$)  # match a position before one or more non-word characters at the end of the string
|         # or
(?<!\W)$  # match the position at the end of the string unless it's preceded by a non-word character
```

If you need to do something else, please rephrase your question and give some examples.

Comment: this is my regex code

Wholesale
replace
home >  
replace
 > 
replace :

this is what iam using it on

Home > Wholesale Cell Phones > Wholesale HiPhone

this changes everytime to something new

here is my output thus far 
Cell Phones: HiPhone
now i need to add an S to the end of it but becouse this changes everytie i cant just 
do hiphone 
replaces hiphones

Comment: Sure, but can't you maniplate the string you read in before you write it out to your page? You can then use the `+ "s"` on your regex output?